# Distinct is not working with Realm Objects results

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to get the distinct objects based on ID, but I am not able to do this. I am facing following error

> Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred

Take a look at following picture and let me know what is the problem Please help me. I am stuck in it

[image]

Comment: Never include code as a screenshot in your question. Include it as text using proper code formatting and clearly marking in your question which line of code produces the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the type signature of `distinct(by:)` (`func distinct<S>(by keyPaths: S) -> Results<Person> where S : Sequence, S.Element == String`) you can see that it expects an input argument of type `Sequence<String>`. Moreover, looking at the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/3.13.1/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:10RealmSwift7ResultsC8distinct2byACyxGqd___tSTRd__SS7ElementRtd__lF) of the method, it tells you that you need to pass in the keyPaths as `String`s that you want to use produce distinct results.

So using the `Dog` class example from the official documentation, if you wanted to produce distinct results based on the `name` property, your function call would look like this:

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0
}

realm.objects(Dog.self).distinct(by: ["name"])
```

Comment: can you tell me how I can use Subquery with a condition ?

Comment: @A.s.ALI you should create a new question regarding that, since that's unrelated to this question about using `distinct`, but if you link the new question here in comments, I'll be happy to have a look